# how to insall and configure privoxy in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, proxy, adblock, privoxy

which is the best way to install configure privoxy in ubuntu 14.04 as adblock plus is really heavy and makes pages like facebook to be very slow even on a computer with good configuration. please help me out to configure the privoxy .
here is the link for its home page[privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install privoxy
```

to install privoxy.
After you installed it successfully you will have a look at http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/quickstart.html#QUICKSTART-AD-BLOCKING where you are introduced using privoxy for ad blocking.
`/etc/privoxy` is where all the configuration is stored.
Furthermore you can view and edit your configuration here: http://config.privoxy.org/show-status